# Space-after gets ignored if I use a block-container inside a list-block

Tags: xsl-fo

I have an XML (user manual) that I'm trying to format using XSL-FO. In the manual, one of the styles we use is a List Note which is part of a list (bullet list or numbered list). for example:

- List Bullet text

  ---

  List Note text

  ---

The note has top and bottom borders. I'm trying to create some space below the border of the note.

The combined FO file that goes into my renderer (Antennahouse) looks like this:

```
<fo:list-item font-family="DIN-RegularAlternate" font-size="8pt" line-height="13pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" space-before="2pt" space-after="2pt" keep-with-previous="10">
<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
    <fo:block margin-left="0pt">-</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
    <!--List Bullet-->
    <fo:block background-color="transparent" font-family="DIN-RegularAlternate" font-size="8pt" line-height="13pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" space-before="2pt" space-after="2pt">List Bullet text
        </fo:block>
    <!--List Note-->
    <fo:block-container start-indent="10mm" border-bottom="0.75pt solid rgb-icc(34,73,146,#Separation, 'PANTONE 287 C', 100%)" border-top="0.75pt solid rgb-icc(34,73,146,#Separation, 'PANTONE 287 C', 100%)" keep-together.within-column="always" space-before="0pt" space-after="12pt">
        <fo:block background-color="transparent" font-family="DIN-RegularAlternate" font-size="7pt" line-height="13pt" font-style="italic" space-before="0pt" space-after="0pt" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0,#CMYK,0%,0%,0%,80%)" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="0pt" padding-right="6pt" start-indent="0pt" end-indent="6pt">Note text
            </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:list-item-body>
```

The block-container is part of the List Note template. I've given this block-container a Space-below attribute. But I can't get it to work: the space below this note stubbornly stays at 0 points. I've tried using various attributes:

```
space-after.minimum="12pt" space-after.optimum="12pt" space-after.precedence="force"
```

I can get it to work if I move the block-container outside of the list-block. But that's undesirable because this note style must be usable inside numbered lists; if the note block is outside the list-block, the numbering of the list will restart. 
I can also get a nice space below the List Bullet, it's just the note that's giving me trouble here.
I've concluded that the combination of a block-container inside a list-block leads to trouble.

How can I control the space below the border of the note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the space-after attribute is honored only when you have two blocks that are siblings. I ended up adding the space-after to the list-block:

```
<xsl:if test="(./para/@stylename='List Note') or (./para/@stylename='List Note 2')">
    <xsl:attribute name="space-after">6pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

A colleague suggested using margin-bottom instead of space-after in my original code, because margin-bottom is honored between blocks that aren't siblings. I haven't tried that yet though.